# How to findById in Mongo, because of different format _id in database and API response

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using mongoDB - saving works well, but I have problem with findById:

```
@Repository
public class DataRepository {


    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DataRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public DBObject save(DBObject jsonToSave, String collectionName) {
        return mongoTemplate.save(jsonToSave, collectionName);
    }

}
```

In my database _id is stored normally:
[image]

but, when I get Api response I got _id in weird format and I dont know how to us this _id object to query:

```
"_id": {
      "timestamp": 1560243698,
      "machineIdentifier": 777068,
      "processIdentifier": -26590,
      "counter": 14453904,
      "timeSecond": 1560243698,
      "time": 1560243698000,
      "date": 1560243698000
    },
```

Part of my controller which returns _id in weird format:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody String json) {

        DBObject dbObject = BasicDBObject.parse(json);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dataRepository.save(dbObject, serviceName));
    }
```

I there any way to return _id in format like it is in database?